How to get specific cookies in Playwright on Python?
import asyncio
import re

from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Playwright, expect


async def geochange(playwright: Playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = await chromium.launch()
    context = await browser.new_context()
    page = await context.new_page()
    await page.goto("https://google.com")
    await page.locator(".popup__close").click()
    geo_cookies = await page.context.cookies()
    print(geo_cookies)

I have the codeblock, and I need to get specific cookie, but no idea what I need to put in url at await page.context.cookies().
When I run this block I get full cookies, but I need only "lim" from this part:
{'name': 'siteCityCode', 'value': 'lim'....


geo_cookies is a list, just get the cookie by name.

This question is similar to: How to get a value from a dict in a list of dicts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is unrelated to Playwright, just a basic list of dicts search question. You can adapt this to your list/dict structure: next(x for x in geo_cookies if x["name"] == "sameCityCode")["value"], assuming you want to search by name.
